# How to map one-to-one relation without join column (entities are joined via their IDs)?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

In my work, I am trying to map the legacy database scheme with Doctrine. I can't change this scheme, because it is used by other company applications. Here is a brief scheme overview:

Table - global_register_item

```
ID | NAME                                      | DTYPE
1  | "global register item with article #1"    | law_regulation
2  | "global register item without article #1" | financial_reporter
3  | "global register item without article #2" | law_regulation
4  | "global register item without article #3" | law_regulation
5  | "global register item with article #2"    | financial_reporter
```

Table - article

```
ID | SID | other fields which I actually do not need
1  | 89  | ...
5  | 45  | ...
```

Table - law_regulation

```
ID | other fields
1  | ...
3  | ...
4  | ...
```

Table - financial_reporter

```
ID | other fields
2  | ...
5  | ...
```

So **global_register_item** is a parent and **law_regulation** and **financial_reporter** inherit from this table. To solve this I used [class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) and it works fine.

The problem is a relation between **global_register_item** and **article**. It is one-to-one relation and joining is done via their ID columns (if there is a record in **global_register_item** with relation to **article**, there is a record in **article** table with the same ID). But some records in **global_register_item** doesn't have record in **article**. Is there any way how to map this relation with Doctrine?

**EDIT 1**

Here is my PHP code from the project. Btw. I only need to read records. And I need to get information about SID column to my GlobalRegisterItem entity.

Class GlobalRegisterItem

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="global_register_item")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="DTYPE", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "law_regulation" = "App\Entity\LawRegulation",
 *     "financial_reporter" = "App\Entity\FinancialReporter"})
 */
abstract class GlobalRegisterItem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
     private $name;

     /**
      * Article|null
      * HOW TO MAP THIS?
      */
     private $article;
}
```

Class Article

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="SID", type="int")
     */
     private $sid;
}
```

Class LawRegulation

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="law_regulation")
 */
class LawRegulation extends GlobalRegisterItem
{
    /** SOME MAPPED FIELDS */
}
```

Class FinancialReporter

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="law_regulation")
 */
class FinancialReporter extends GlobalRegisterItem
{
    /** SOME MAPPED FIELDS */
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? The `DTYPE` column is sometimes `null` and sometimes `"article"` but you still want to use it as the discriminator-column? Do I get that correctly? Explain the "some records in global_register_item doesn't have record in article" part a little better please.

Comment: In which column is the relation between `law_regulation` or `global_register_item` and `article` stored exactly? I don't see a join-column anywhere in your question.

Comment: Did you just try to edit your question with a [new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5594333/otak)?

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich as I understand it, `article` is just a nullable `OneToOne` to `global_register_item` where the join column is the `id` on both tables, with `article` having an identifier of type `NONE`.

Comment: @msg Your understanding of situation is right. I added some code and "data" for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`OneToOne` bidirectional relation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional), in the `Article` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GlobalRegisterItem", inversedBy="article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $item;
```

And reference it in your `GlobalRegisterItem` class:

```
 /**
  * Article|null
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="item")
  */
 private $article;

 /**
  * Gets the sid of the article (if any).
  * @returns int|null
  */
 public function getArticleSid()
 {
   if (null !== $this->article) {
     return $this->article->getSid();
   }
   return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach how to solve this (if you just need to read data) is:

Create view from **global_register_item** and **article**

```
SELECT global_register_item.*, article.SID AS `SID`
FROM global_register_item
LEFT JOIN article ON global_register_item.id = article.id

ID | NAME                                      | DTYPE              | SID
1  | "global register item with article #1"    | law_regulation     | 89
2  | "global register item without article #1" | financial_reporter | NULL
3  | "global register item without article #2" | law_regulation     | NULL
4  | "global register item without article #3" | law_regulation     | NULL
5  | "global register item with article #2"    | financial_reporter | 45
```

Class GlobalRegisterItem

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="global_register_item_view")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="DTYPE", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "law_regulation" = "App\Entity\LawRegulation",
 *     "financial_reporter" = "App\Entity\FinancialReporter"})
 */
abstract class GlobalRegisterItem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
     private $name;

     /**
      * int|null
      * @ORM\Column(name="SID", type="integer")
      */
     private $sid;
}
```

I think this is far from being optimal, but this is the best solution I could come up with.